# How to find largest files in a dir - ignoring directory sizes

Tags: linux, awk, ls, du

I want to do something like this

```
du -a | sort -rn | head
```

But I want to extract files only, ignoring directories.

To be clear, I want to traverse through all sub-directories but I don't want to find directory sizes. Just files sizes.

*UPDATE*

I also want to return the full path of the files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
find <path> -type f -exec du -a{} + | sort -rn | head
```

Taken from http://unix-linux.itags.org/q_unix-linux-programming_84920.html

Comment: Just a note this works on Debian but not on BSD Unix (as tested)

Comment: @superspace: It might be useful to say exactly how it doesn't work. My guess is that changing `+` to `\;` might be all that you need to change.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson True. + resulted in this error: find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+". However, replacing + with \; resulted in other errors: du: illegal option -- .

Comment: UPDATE: This works on BSD (note space between -a and {}):
find . -type f -exec du -a {} \; | sort -rn | head

Comment: changing from + to \; also makes the script run 10x slower :(

Answer (score 2):

One way to find the largest file in a directory:

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -1S | head -n 1
```

Comment: Does everything I've requested, but beaten to the pip by the other answer.

Comment: @superspace: That's ok, our answers are a little different anyway. I didn't realize you wanted the filesize printed ahead of the directory name.

Comment: The file size was a bonus. He pipped you by coming in first :) Otherwise I would have awarded the answer to you cause as I said you fulfilled the requirements of the question.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add my solution although it's not as complete as the one by @Michael Plotke

```
ls -lR | egrep "^-" | awk '{ print $5, "\t", $8 }' | sort -rn | head
```

**UPDATE 1**

I've now had to use this script on BSD unix (which I did not originally intended to do) and found Michael's solution doesn't work.

By incorporating @steve's solution into mine, this solution is more usable on BSD systems:

```
find . -type f | xargs ls -lS | awk '{ print $5, "\t", $9 }' | head
```

**UPDATE 2**

Further refinement. Resolves issues with unusual filenames (eg. spaces)

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lS | awk '{ print $5, "\t", $9 }' | head
```

**Note**: I found this solution to be significantly faster on WSL (windows subsystem Linux) than the accepted solution.

In a directory with about 1000 files, this solution takes seconds whereas the accepted answer took tens of minutes.

Comment: This sub-obtimal solution works on Debian

Comment: Instead of the pipe to `head`, `awk` can accomplish it too. Simply try piping into: `awk 'NR<=10 { print $5 "\t" $9 }'`